# Why can't a matrix of linearly independent functions have determinant vanishing everywhere?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have an <s>affine algebraic variety</s> set $X$  <s>over an algebraically closed field $k$</s>   and  <s>regular</s>  functions $f_1,...,f_m:X\rightarrow k$ which are linearly independent over the field $k$. Why do there exist $m$ points $x_1,...,x_m\in X$ such that the matrix $$(f_i(x_j))_{1\leq i,j\leq m}$$ is invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to your question:

By hypothesis, span$\lbrace \left(f_1(x),\dots,f_m(x)\right)\in k^m:x\in X \rbrace$ cannot have dimension $<m$. Hence this set contains a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess this has nothing to do with algebraic geometry. Construct a matrix as follows. The first column is any nonzero vector, $v_1 \in k^m$. There exists $x_1\in X$ such that $(f_1(x_1),...,f(x_m))\cdot v_1 \neq 0 $ (by linear independence). Now choose $v_2$ orthogonal to $(f_1(x_1),...,f_m(x_1))$. There exists $x_2$ such that $(f_1(x_2),...,f_m(x_2))\cdot v_2 \neq 0$. Now choose $v_3$ orthongoal to $(f_1(x_1),...,f_m(x_1))$ and $(f_1(x_2),...,f_m(x_2))$. There exists $x_3$ such that $(f_1(x_2),...,f_m(x_2))\cdot v_3 \neq 0$... Continuing in that way gives a matrix $(v_1,...,v_m)$ whose product with the matriix $(f_i(x_j))$ is lower triangular with nonzero diagonal elements.